# How can I show that following two sequences have same order of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $X_n=o(Y_n)$ (little oh notation) and $Y_n=o(X_n)$,

then they have the same order of convergence (linear, quadratic, superlinear)

How can I show this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a *big* $O(\cdot)$ instead? (Basically, your assumption with $o(\cdot)$'s is not possible.)

Comment: Is this even possible? You have on the one hand that $\frac{x_n}{y_n} \rightarrow 0$ and on the other hand, $\frac{y_n}{x_n} \rightarrow 0$. This can't really happen.

Comment: yeah, this is one of the exam question and I am not sure whether it is possible. For Clement,C, it is little Oh notation

Comment: @user268336 You are looking for sequences such that $\lvert x_n\rvert \ll \lvert y_n\rvert $ *and* $\lvert x_n\rvert \gg \lvert y_n\rvert $. It's not possible.

Comment: If that little O notation is replaced with big O notation, is this valid?

Comment: It is possible with little o's   but only if $x_n=y_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ because we have $|x_n|\leq |y_n|/2 \wedge |y_n|\leq |x_n|/2$ for all but finitely many $n$.